# How to use variable while in a "string.example" function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay so basically I have a json file, which it will call the json variable according to the argument that is put into the file, I need to use a variable to call the "jsondata.args[0];" that I want, but instead of getting the data from the json file, it just lists "jsondata.theargument"

I have tried to first set args[0] to a variable, then do "let var = database.argvar" then I tried doing (`database.${argvar}`) and ive tried directly passing the data through the argument as listed above. Everything just returns the text instead of actually getting the data from the json.

```
var exoid = args[0];
let exocheck = database.exoid;
let exoinfo = (`${user}:${pass}`);
  if (exoinfo == exocheck) {
```

As I said, the output is only the text "database.exoid" or "database.AA" instead of getting the actual data from the json document.

Comment: `let var = database.argvar` will throw a `SyntaxError`, `var` is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
let exoid = args[0];
let exocheck = database[exoid];
```

This lets you access a property of database by a variable. Otherwise you are literally looking for the the "exoid" property of the database object. I hope this makes sense.